# Convert std::shared_ptr<char> to std::shared_ptr<unsigned char>

Tags: c++, c++11

Is there a good way to convert a `shared_ptr<char>` to a `shared_ptr<unsigned char>`?

I came up with the following but it doesn't look very clean.

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    std::shared_ptr<char> p1 = std::make_shared<char>();

    std::shared_ptr<unsigned char> p2 = std::shared_ptr<unsigned char>(
        reinterpret_cast<unsigned char*>(p1.get()),
        [p1](unsigned char*) {});
}
```

Comment: I originally didn't understand the lambda capture and thought there is a bug, but having thought it through, I don't think there is.  In fact, this seems like a more cumbersome, but a more universal solution than `reinterpret_pointer_cast`.  In fact, `reinterpret_pointer_cast` seems like a bad idea.  It only removes the reinterpretation one level away.  If there is a multiple levels of pointers (eg, `***char`), it breaks down and creates a situation where more semantic tricks become necessary.  Whereas the lambda capture can be applied more uniformly in such scenarios.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a ready-made function for what you're doing, [`reinterpret_pointer_cast`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/pointer_cast):

```
std::shared_ptr<unsigned char> p2 =
    std::reinterpret_pointer_cast<unsigned char>(p1);
```

The resulting pointer shares ownership with the original pointer.

By contrast, your own code ends up with two *separate* ownership groups. If the original group dies first, your new pointer will be left dangling!

You *can* use `p1.get()` and also share ownership with the original pointer if you use the aliasing constructor. That's in fact how those cast helpers are implemented (see link):

```
std::shared_ptr<unsigned char> p2(p1, reinterpret_cast<unsigned char*>(p1.get()));
```

This creates a shared pointer that shares ownership with `p1` but stores the value given as the second constructor argument.

Comment: do you have an implementation for `reinterpret_pointer_cast`? I couldn't find this in my compiler.

Comment: What the answer doesn't say: **if you need to do this, something is probably wrong**.

Comment: @tcb: Simply click on the link. You'll find out that it's a C++11 feature. Now you can go and find out whether it's one of the C++11 features that your compiler supplies. Some folks will tell you "if your compiler doesn't have all the C++11 features you are some kind of medieval cretin" but those folks are wrong; those of us actually using C++ in the real world as opposed to just hobbyist banter after often stuck on embryonic C++11 _if we're lucky_, so I have your back ;)

Comment: the link says it is a c++17 feature

Comment: @tcb: Okay, to be fair, now I feel silly, because I can't read ;)

Comment: Let's just agree to hold my above comment for 10 years then yeah? ;)

Comment: The link contains a possible implementation using the aliasing constructor, I can reproduce this here in case you don't have this feature (and don't want to go via `void*` and back).

Comment: @tcb: Please see updated answer for a manual version; I had meant to post that earlier but got sidetracked onto something else.

Comment: @KerrekSB: It happens ^_^